# Unity 3d Slider Value on Android resets to min value

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using standard unity slider, on 2018.2.12f1 (Personal) version.

Lets say I have slider with minValue = 1 and maxValue = 10.

Then I slide it to 6.

When pressing slider again on a palce where 8 would normaly be I get always 2 events: first one tells slider was set on its minValue, and then second one (1 frame later) returns correct value.

Which results in ugly 1 frame flash on the slider as well as my gameObject which scale it controls.

This happens only on ANDROID, works fine in : webGl, unityEditor.

UPDATE:

My question was how to resolve the issue.

I found out its caused by free asset : Touch Script and its Touch Script Manager.

I guess the asset is so outdate and no longer maintaned that such issues are bound to happen. Thats why theres nothing left to do with it except moving on.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You should post your slide controller code, so everyone can trace where are you setting again the value to min